# Como inserir valor retornado em campos de formulário com jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Preciso, após efetuar consulta em `BD` inserir valores retornados em campos de um form, pois vou usar esses campos para efetuar uma alteração no `BD`, a chamada para pesquisa está funcionando corretamente e está configurada dessa forma, chamo a função `BuscaDados` passando os parâmetros `Operacao` e `IdFase` para a página `pProcessoFase.php` que me retorna os valores pesquisados mas no retorno não estou conseguindo atribuir os valores nos campos do formulário, dei um console.log no retorno e me vem isso  vejam:

```
[{"Descricao":"controle","Data":"2015-09-03","Hora":"17:36:00","IdTipoFase":1}]
function BuscaDados(IdFase) {
    var params = {
        Operacao: 'BuscaUnica',
        IdFase: IdFase
    };      
    $.post(
        'pProcessoFase.php',
        params,
        function( json, textStatus, jQxhr ){
            if (jQxhr.responseText != "[]") {
                try {
                    if (jQxhr.readyState === 4) {
                        if (jQxhr.status === 200) {
                            var registro = JSON.parse(jQxhr.responseText);

                            console.log("RESPOSTA DA CONSULTA: " + jQxhr.responseText);

                            //Atribui valores aos campos
                            $('#sDescricao').val(registro[0].Descricao);
                            $('#dData').val(registro[0].Data);  
                            $('#dHora').val(registro[0].Hora);  
                            $('#IdTipoFas').val(registro[0].IdTipoFas);                         
                        } else {
                            var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                                title: 'ERRO',
                                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                                message: 'Ocorreu um erro na requisição dos dados. Tente novamente.'
                            }); 
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch( e ) {
                    console.log(e);
                    var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                        title: 'ERRO',
                        type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                        message: 'Ocorreu um erro na requisição dos dados. Tente novamente.'
                    }); 
                }
            }
        },
        'json'
    )
    .fail(function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
        try {
            var json = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
            var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'ERRO',
                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                message: json.msg
            }); 
        } catch(e) { 
            var dialogInstance = BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'ERRO',
                type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_DANGER,
                message: json.msg
            }); 
        }
    });
}
```

Pesquisa na página `pProcessoFase.php`:

```
if ($_POST["Operacao"] == 'BuscaUnica') {

    $sql = "SELECT Descricao, Data, Hora, IdTipoFase FROM gerFaseContrato WHERE IdFase = '". $_POST['IdFase']."' ";

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $data = array();    
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
        $stmt->close();
    }else{
        $aretorno["msg"] = "Ocorreu um erro na inclusão dos dados: " . $stmt->error . ". Verifique.";
        $aretorno["status"] = "ERRO";
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($aretorno);
    }

    $conn->close();
    exit;
}
```

O formulário onde estou tentando inserir as informações:

```html
<body>
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frmDadosFase">
  <fieldset>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="sDescricao">Descrição</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="sDescricao" name="sDescricao"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="dData">Data</label>
      <div class="col-md-4" id="sandbox-container">
        <div class="input-group date">
          <input name="dData" type="text" class="form-control" id="dData">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="dHora">Hora</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <input id="dHora" name="dHora" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" type="time">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="IdTipoFase">Tipo Fase</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="IdTipoFase" name="IdTipoFase"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que dá? o que está a faltar? o que dá `console.log(registro[0].Descricao);`?

Comment: Olá @Sergio, ai é que está não me acusa nenhum erro e todos os campos que preciso são retornados.

Comment: Então o que não está a funcionar? o console.log que referi em cima funciona?

Comment: Sim, o console.log traz os dados pesquisados e não estou conseguindo joga-los nos campos do form.

Comment: Qual é o HTML de `#sDescricao` por exemplo? podes colocar o resto também?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Segui um exemplo funcionado:

```js
var jsonString = '[{"Descricao":"controle","Data":"2015-09-03","Hora":"17:36:00","IdTipoFase":1}]';

var registro = JSON.parse(jsonString);

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#sDescricao').val(registro[0].Descricao);
  $('#dData').val(registro[0].Data);
  $('#dHora').val(registro[0].Hora);
  $('#IdTipoFase').val(registro[0].IdTipoFase);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="frmDadosFase">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="sDescricao">Descrição</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="sDescricao" name="sDescricao"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="dData">Data</label>
        <div class="col-md-4" id="sandbox-container">
          <div class="input-group date">
            <input name="dData" type="text" class="form-control" id="dData"> <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span> 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="dHora">Hora</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="dHora" name="dHora" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" type="time">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="IdTipoFase">Tipo Fase</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <textarea class="form-control" id="IdTipoFase" name="IdTipoFase"></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Olá @henriquedpereira, obrigado pelo exemplo e pelo trabalho de montar todo o esquema.